Flutter State Management - Initial State with params
I'm new to Flutter and I want to know if is possible to pass an initial value for a parameter of a Initial State while in state management:
This is my "Initial State":
class HomeInitialState extends HomeCubitState {
  final List<RecipeEntity> recipes;

  const HomeInitialState({required this.recipes});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [recipes];
}

On my Cubit I initialize my HomeInitialState with super constructor:
class HomeCubit extends Cubit<HomeCubitState> {
  HomeCubit({required this.homeUseCase}) : super(HomeInitialState());

  final HomeUseCase homeUseCase;
  
  late List<RecipeEntity> receitas;

  

  void filterEvent(String tipo, BuildContext context) async {
    emit(HomeFilteredState(
      receitasFiltradas: [
        RecipeEntity(id: 2, nome: 'Lasanha', tempoPreparo: 60, tipo: 'Salgado', imagem: Image.asset('assets/images/lasanha.png', width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.30))
      ],
      tipoFiltrado: tipo
    ));
  }


  String _mapFailureToMessage(Failure failure) {
    switch (failure.runtimeType) {
      case ServerFailure:
        return serverFailureMessage;
      case CacheFailure:
        return cacheFailureMessage;
      default: return generalFailureMessage;
    }
  }
}

I need to initialize with my "recipes" list full

As HomeInitialState has required field recipes, you MUST set initial value for recipes in cubit super: : super(HomeInitialState(...here...));

You can use factory constructor to your state like this:
class HomeInitialState extends HomeCubitState {
  final List<RecipeEntity> recipes;

  const HomeInitialState({required this.recipes});

  factory HomeInitialState.initial() => HomeInitialState(
    recipes: _yourInitData(),
  );
  
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [recipes];
}

Then at your BlocProvider in your UI:
BlocProvider<HomeInitialBloc>(
  create: (context) => HomeInitialBloc(HomeInitialState.initial()),
  child: ...,
)


Thank you for your answer! Do you know how to do with BlocBuilder instead?
